# Serialize DbGeography to Json in MVC without Json.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Currently I have to set all DbGeography types to null before letting converting it to Json. Is there a way to add a new converter for this type? I know I could use Json.Net and add a converter for the DbGeography type in the model, but we don't want to use Json.Net.

```
        //Json converter fails to convert this. 
        deviceInfo.DeviceData.DeviceLocation = null;

        return Json(deviceInfo);
```

I find it hard to believe Microsoft would make MVC's JsonResult not be extensible.

Comment: why can't you extend it? you could just make a `CustomJsonResult` using `JsonResult` as a base and add any extra logic there

Comment: Where do I add logic?

Comment: override the `ExecuteResult` method